# How do I get serialize data on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

How do I get serialize data on wordpress database?

Example

```
option_name               option_value
-----------------------------------------------------------
widget_example-widget     a:3:{i:2;a:0:{}i:6;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:14:"Example Widget";s:4:"name";s:8:"John Doe";s:3:"age";s:2:"30";s:3:"sex";s:4:"male";}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

Example I want to call `sex` and I use

```
$sex = get_option('widget_example-widget');
echo $sex['sex'];
```

It return empty and when try `var_dump` result like below

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "Example Widget"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["sex"]=>
    string(4) "male"
  }
  ["_multiwidget"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Actually I can retrieve this data by add  `$sex['6']['sex']` but the problem here the `[6]=>` is dynamic. When we activate/deactivate the widget it can be in another value.

Question

How do I get a correct data for this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you really want, but maybe try a function that check every array to see if "sex" index isset, and return the value if it is. Not very efficient but it should do it anyway...

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;s:12:"Sample array";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:5:"Apple";i:1;s:6:"Orange";}}';

$unserialized = unserialize($data);

print_r($unserialized);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sample array
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => Orange
        )
)
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer